# Parsing XML Elements using unmarshaller

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, jaxb

I have the following XML

```
<Messages>
<PopUpMessages>
<Message no=”1” type=”game” name=”DONATION”>
Congratulation You won
</Message>
</PopUpMessages>
```

I'm using this http://code.google.com/p/asaxb/, its for Actionscript, and it has the basic functionality of JAXB.

The problem is I can get the PopUpMessages, and everything is fine, but I can not get the **content

" Congratulation You Won"**, which is inside the Message.

The definitions are:

```
    package
    { 
    [XmlRootNode(name = 'Message')]
    public class Message {

        [XmlAttribute(name = "no")]
        public var no:Number;
        [XmlAttribute(name = "type")]
        public var type:String;
        [XmlAttribute(name = "imageSource")]
        public var imageSource:String;
        [XmlAttribute(name = "name")]
        public var name:String;
        [XmlAttribute(name = "k")]
        public var k:String;
    }    
    }

   // The class that I unmarsahall 
    public class GCPResponse {      
        [XmlElement(name="Messages")]
        public var message:Messages;    
    }

    package
    { 
    [XmlRootNode(name = "PopUpMessages")]
    public class PopUpMessages {

        [XmlElement(name="Message")]

        public var  message:Message;     
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leverage the `@XmlValue` annotation.

Comment: That's what I have noticed right, the library doesn't support it. :/